# Passing parameter in html input tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass 2 parameter through the value attribute of a input tag.

Below is my code, i only managed to pass the skuCode:

```
 <input type=hidden value=".$row["skuCode"]."&".$row["category"]." name=skuCode>
 <input type=submit value=Edit>
```

Is it possible to pass 2 parameter?
How should I go about doing it?

Comment: you can pass them comma separted in case its not working

Comment: Is that PHP that's joining the contents?

Comment: u need to split while retrieving those params...

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type=hidden value=".$row["skuCode"]." name=skuCode>
   <input type=hidden value=".$row["category"]." name=category>
```

Unless there's a very good reason not to, this is the way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type=hidden value="<?php echo $row['skuCode'].'&'.$row['category'];?>" name=skuCode>
<input type=submit value=Edit>
```

It will pass the value as 'value1&value2' which you using string manipulation can break into 2 values and use according to your requirements.

I hope my answer helps ! ;)